# Как прикрепить блок к самому низу страницы?

Tags: html, css, position

Делаю позицию `position: fixed; bottom:0;` но он прикрепляется при этом ко дну экрана, но не страницы. Как можно сделать так, чтобы при любой высоте страницы, блок был прикреплен ко дну страницы?

Comment: Может быть просто ставить блок на дно страницы? После контентного блока

Comment: он и так там. Но позиционирование стоит в главной части экрана зачем то. Сам не понимаю

Comment: Вам **[сюда][1]**.


  [1]: http://habrahabr.ru/post/151320/

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/PGMqs/1/)

```css
.vertical_banner {
    border: 1px solid #E9E3DD;
    float: left;
    height: 210px;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 4px 2px 10px 10px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 117px;
    position: relative;
}

#bottom_link{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.3.2/mootools-yui-compressed.min.js"></script>
<div class="vertical_banner">
    <div id="bottom_link">
         <input type="submit" value="Continue">
       </div>
</div>
```